# Are session and local storage fine for internal applications?

Tags: javascript, security, web, jwt

For internal applications, those that are not on the public internet and only used internally in an organization (also served over HTTPS), is it necessary to store a JWT in a cookie, or are session and local storage fine?

Comment: I think you shouldn't have a different security level internally than you have externally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session/local storages, just like normal cookies, are easily accessible from the client side. The ideal solution would be to use [HTTP Only Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies).

Also remember that your choice will change the way you send/receive your JWT token.

In any case, none of the above solutions would be considered a serious security flaw.

As an additional personal note, the fact that the application is served locally does not necessarily protect it from the same security risks a remotely served application would face.

Comment: Having JWT stored in session or local storage for a public-facing site is not a serious security flaw?

Comment: It would be exactly the same as using traditional cookies. In both cases the token would be saved locally as plain text and could be programmatically accessed. (The difference is that cookies are automatically sent on HTTP requests and can also be programmed to expire locally). Security must be enforced server side with strong token management policies (expiration, IP checking and fingerprinting, etc.). If you don't believe me, visit some of your favorite websites and see stored data through inspector.

Comment: @Graham for locally served applications, IP checking and fingerprinting is a lot easier than on internet.

Comment: It was my understanding that the JWT would not be accessible from a cookie. While session and local storage are accessible through JavaScript injection attacks. Is this not the case?

Comment: @Graham HTTP Only cookies are not programmatically accessible, normal cookies are instead. But data is still saved as plain text. Yes, session/local storages are accessible through injection attacks (normal cookies too), but this doesn't mean HTTP cookies can't be stolen somehow else. To explain my position better I will refer you to an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277003/10035928) I wrote about this. TLDR, no shame for using storage, but use HTTP Only cookies because it takes the same effort and might be safer.